# ¿Cómo hago lo mismo con un solo for?

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Hice este código para imprimir un rombo en la consola. Se lo presenté a mi profesor y me pidió que lo haga con un solo `for`. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x, y,l;

    Console.Write("ingrese un numero para definir la longitud de el rombo: ");

    l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (x = 0; x <= l; x++)
    {
        for (y = l - x; y > 0; y--)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for (y = 0; y < x; y++)
        {
            Console.Write(" *");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
    for(x = 0; x <= l;x++)
    {
        for(y = 0; y <= x; y++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        for(y = l - x -1;y > 0; y--)
        {
            Console.Write(" *");                
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias explicar que es lo que estas tratando de hacer

Comment: Especulando un poco, parece que está intentando construir un rombo en la consola.

Comment: y que es lo que hace tu codigo?

Comment: POn en una imagen la figura que deseas obtener

Comment: @Japv un rombo, si no me crees ejecuta el código.

Comment: Yo no tengo que probar nada, tu eres el que tiene que dar los detalles suficientes para que se te entienda y se te pueda ayudar, hablando claro la tarea es tuya no mia, a mi como tal me da igual

Answer (score 1):

Lo puede hacer con un solo for de esta manera:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       int x, y;

       Console.Write("ingrese un numero para definir la longitud de el rombo: ");

       var l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty);

       DibujarRombo(l);

    }

    public static void DibujarRombo(int l)
    {
        if(l<=0) return;
        var init = l;
        var flag = false;
        var n = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < (l+l)+1; i++)
        {
            var row = string.Empty;
            row = row.PadRight(n,'*');
            row = row.Insert(0,"".PadRight(init));
            Console.WriteLine(row);
            if (init < 1) flag = true;
            if (flag)
            {
                init++;
                n -= 2;
            }
            else
            {
                init--;
                n += 2;
            }

        }

    }
 }
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: bro tengo un problema es que el visual studio dice que el programa no tiene ningun metodo main estatico adecuado para un punto de entrada podrias pasar el codigo completo

Comment: Agregado espero que te funcione.